# Trouble Loading libgphoto2.dylib into python

Tags: python, macos, camera, ctypes, libgphoto2

I have gphoto installed properly and I can use all the features with my camera, but for some reason

```
gphoto = ctypes.CDLL('libgphoto2.dylib')
```

Throws an error.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> gphoto = ctypes.CDLL('libgphoto2.dylib')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libgphoto2.dylib, 6): image not found
>>>
```

I installed libgphoto2 using macports, and like I said gphoto works fine:

```
$ gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download
    New file is in location /capt0000.nef on the camera                            
    Saving file as capt0000.nef
    Deleting file /capt0000.nef on the camera
    Deleting 'capt0000.nef' from folder '/'...
```

So I don't understand why gphoto2 can use libgphoto2 but ctypes can't. Any suggestions? I'm very new to this so it's probably a really basic, stupid mistake.

Comment: `find_library` doesn't output anything, just gives me a new line in the shell, no matter if I give it `gphoto2` or `libgphoto2.dylib` or anything else...

Comment: Thank you for commenting though!

Comment: `otool -L` says it'll "Display the names and version numbers of the shared libraries that the object file uses,  As well  as the shared library ID if the file is a shared library." but when I run it as 


`$ otool -L libgphoto2.dylib` or `$ otool -L gphoto2` or `$ otool -L libgphoto2` I just get 

`error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: gphoto (No such file or directory)`

Comment: You need to give it the full path to gphoto2. Find it with `which gphoto2`.

Comment: I haven't tested this fully, but based on `>>> import ctypes
>>> gphoto = ctypes.CDLL('/opt/local/lib/libgphoto2.6.dylib')
>>> 
` I think It'll work! Thank you so much!